# Hibernate @SecondaryTable - Specifying foreign key of primary table

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables:

1. language

   ```
   CREATE TABLE language (
     id   BIGSERIAL,
     name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
   );
   ```
2. translation

   ```
   CREATE TABLE translation (
     id                BIGSERIAL,
     language_id       BIGINT REFERENCES language (id),
     translation_key   TEXT NOT NULL,
     translation_value TEXT NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
   );
   ```

   And I would like to get such entity, where translation table (primary table) joins language table by language_id from primary table. **Problem:** at the moment it joins by translation PK(id).

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "translation")
   @SecondaryTable(name = "language", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id"))
   public class Translation {

       @Id
       @Column(name = "id")
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       private long id;

       @Column(table = "language", name = "name")
       // ON translation.language_id = language.id
       private String language;

       @Column(name = "translation_key")
       private String translationKey;

       @Column(name = "translation_value")
       private String translationValue;

       // getters and setters
   }
   ```

   Where I should specify it in my code to do it correctly?
   **SQL example:** `SELECT t.id, l.name, translation_key, translation_value FROM translation t INNER JOIN language l on t.language_id = l.id;`

Comment: You do understand that the relation between entries in a primary and a secondary table is necessarily one-to-one, right?

Comment: Why it is one to one? I think different translations can have the same language. So, it's many-to-one, i think.

Comment: Well then, you cannot join a secondary table to a primary table using anything other than its id. `language` is not part of the `Translation` entity's id

Comment: And what I should do to get what I want? To create separate language entity?

Comment: If you want a many-to-one association, you cannot use a secondary table. Use a separate `Language` entity and a `@ManyToOne` instead

Comment: @crizzis Can you please add this as the answer? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `@SecondaryTable` for the purpose you describe.

`@SecondaryTable` is used when a single entity is spread across multiple tables. Each of these 'pieces' of the entity must be *privately owned* by the entity, and is in a one-to-one relation with every other 'piece'.

If you want a many-to-one relation between translations and languages, you need to use `@ManyToOne` (and create a separate `Language` entity) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```java
@SecondaryTable(name = "language")
```

this way it is going to generate value for the translation id and insert it to the language foreign key automatically if you specify `pkJoinColumn` it is going to relate the tables through the primary key while if you don't mention that, it would do it through the foreign key. After that you need to create a trigger and sequence for the language table id column. It should work.